# template_preprocess custom block type

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I have a custom block type with two different fields.
What I am trying to accomplish is, to hide the first field if the second is not empty.

That seems like something that could be done in template_preprocess, but where would I put it and what would be my template?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize twig's if/else condition:

- Find the twig's [template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/locating-template-files-with-debugging) file for your custom block using [twig debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)
- use twig's if/else syntax ([reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html))

```
{% if field_NAME_OF_YOUR_SECOND_FIELD.0 == false %}
    {{ field_NAME_OF_YOUR_FIRST_FIELD.0 }}
{% endif %}
```

check [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-drupal-8-field-values-in-twig-22b80cb609bd) for extracting the values of different fields

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing the `block_content` template was [considered](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2704331#comment-11863202) [undesireable](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2366687#comment-9301441), and they suppressed the functionality. There is a [module on github](https://github.com/swentel/block_content_template) that provides this functionality, but since it lacks composer support, you might just copy it into your project.

All that said, you should find that `template_preprocess_block` allows access to what you want, and this might work:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  unset($variables['content']['field_custom'][0]);
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Custom block type is available in `$variables['content']['body']['#bundle']`
Refer the below sample function

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['content']['body']['#bundle'] == 'my_block_type') {
    // Do whatever specific to the block type.
  } 
}
```

Adding a bit more information as per @berliner commented

```
$variables['content']['#block_content'] //will hold the content entity

$variables['content']['#block_content']->id() //will give you the content id, ie. the custom block content id
```

In order to alter any field you could apply logic inside the conditional statement

Ref. belwo code where the values are assigned to a drupalSettings js variable.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    
        if($variables['content']['body']['#bundle'] == 'my_custom_block_type')
        {
        $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['block_content_id']=$variables['content']['#block_content']->id();
            
        $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['full_content']=$variables['content'];
        }

}
```

I would prefer to log drupalSettings.full_content to a javascript console, which would give a bigger picture of the whole variables and manipulate accordingly
Ref: JS function

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

Drupal.behaviors.myCustomJSFunction = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      console.log(drupalSettings.full_content);
        }
    };
    
     })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings, window.Cookies);
```

Comment: This could be improved, as it doesn't seem to fully address the original problem of this question. It shows how to identify the block, but not how to modify it.